# Implementation of StyleGAN by NVlabs shows syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, generative-adversarial-network

I was trying to implement [StyleGAN](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan) on my local system and was not able to run because of *invalid syntax* in the `__init__.py` file.

```
submit_config: SubmitConfig = None # Package level variable for SubmitConfig which is only valid when inside the run function.
```

This line is after all the imports and I am unsure if I must make changes to the official code or if I am missing a dependency. The `__init__.py` file can be found [here](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan/blob/master/dnnlib/__init__.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#specification) and it was introduced in Python3.6.

> This PEP aims at adding syntax to Python for annotating the types of
>   variables (including class variables and instance variables), instead
>   of expressing them through comments:
>
> ```
> primes: List[int] = []
>
> captain: str  # Note: no initial value!
>
> class Starship:
>     stats: ClassVar[Dict[str, int]] = {}
> ```

The StyleGAN [System Requirements](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan#system-requirements) does mention that they require a Python3.6 installation.

> - 64-bit Python 3.6 installation. We recommend Anaconda3 with numpy 1.14.3 or newer.